# Query for model by key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What I'm trying to do is query the datastore for a model where the key is *not* the key of an object I already have. Here's some code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    partner = db.SelfReferenceProperty()

def text_message(self, msg):
    user = User.get_or_insert(msg.sender)

    if not user.partner:
        # user doesn't have a partner, find them one
        # BUG: this line returns 'user' himself... :(
        other = db.Query(User).filter('partner =', None).get()
        if other:
            # connect users
        else:
            # no one to connect to!
```

The idea is to find another `User` who doesn't have a partner, that isn't the user we already know.

I've tried `filter('key !=, user.key())`, `filter('__key__ !=, user.key())` and a couple others, and nothing returns another `User` who doesn't have a partner.
 `filter('foo !=, user.key())` also returns nothing, for the record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a really easy way around this: Retrieve two records, and filter out the user's own one, if it's present.

```
def text_message(self, msg):
    user = User.get_or_insert(msg.sender)

    if not user.partner:
        # user doesn't have a partner, find them one
        other = db.Query(User).filter('partner =', None).fetch(2)
        other = [u for u in other if u.key() != user.key()]
        if other:
            # connect user with other[0]
        else:
            # no one to connect to!
```

Comment: I thought about this, and it would definitely work, but it seems like a hack.  Is it not possible to just filter by key in a query?

Comment: It is possible, and your queries should work - without more details I can't tell you why they're not. However, they'd also be substantially _less_ efficient than this approach: != queries require two underlying queries to execute, which is a bit of a blunt instrument just to eliminate a single result from the result set.

Comment: Oh, then fetching two is actually better? Interesting.  Here's my code if you're curious: http://gist.github.com/344873

Comment: Yes, fetching two will definitely be better than two separate queries. This is also the approach taken by the crowdguru sample app: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/crowdguru/guru.py#98