# How can I filter by key, or keys, a query in Python for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gqlquery

I have a `query` and I can apply [`filters`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_filter) on them without any problem. This works fine:

```
query.filter('foo =', 'bar')
```

But what if I want to filter my query by `key` or a list of keys?

I have them as `Key()` property or as a `string` and by trying something like this, it didn't work:

```
query.filter('key =', 'some_key')        #no success
query.filter('key IN', ['key1', 'key2']) #no success
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query for model by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521012/query-for-model-by-key)

Comment: @Jason I don't think it's duplicate.. doesn't solve my problem.. I might expand my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst it's possible to filter on key - see @dplouffe's answer - it's not a good idea. 'IN' clauses execute one query for each item in the clause, so you end up doing as many queries as there are keys, which is a particularly inefficient way to achieve your goal.

Instead, use a batch fetch operation, as @Luke documents, then filter any elements you don't want out of the list in your code.

Comment: So it's a bad idea to even use (as @Luke suggested) `models = MyModel.get(Key.from_path(...), ...)`and then filter in the code? or this is what you mean by fetch operation?

Comment: @Lipis That is what I suggest using. get operations are batchable and faster than queries.

Comment: But if I have many entries and I want to return them in part per 10 for example.. I will end up filtering out with some kind of loop (or is there any smarter way?) thousands of possible entries and I can't guarantee that the wanted ones will be in my first fetch().. am I confusing?

Comment: @Lipis How are you getting the list of keys to fetch? It's somewhat odd that you know the exact keys you want to get, but not if they belong in the final result list or not.

Comment: Example: 1000 Users have 1 File each (1000 Files) tagged with the same Tag. This tag contains a list of File keys (I'm using taggable-mixin class.. maybe that's the root of all evil.. but I wanted the tag functionality).. So I want to display the files that have this tag and belog to a specific User..

Comment: @Lipis Why not model the tags as a list of strings or keys on the File itself, instead of the other way around? Then, you can do a single query with equality filters on tag and user.

Comment: @Nick I have no reason to doubt what you're saying, but can you explain to me a bit more what the difference is between using and IN clause and the "batch" method?  Doesn't AppEngine have to get the keys from different shards of data no matter how you request it?  Is it that the batch method "batches' every key from each server together and then requests versus the IN which does 1 query per whether a key is found on the same server or not?

Comment: @dplouffe IN queries are handled in the Python code, and result in the SDK issuing one query for each clause. The query goes through the query planner, which, although it has optimisations for this sort of case, is more involved than simply fetching records. Currently, too, multiple queries are executed in series, not in parallel. Batch gets, in contrast, are sent to the datastore as a single operation, and it simply looks up all the relevant entities in parallel and returns them.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You cannot filter on a Key.</strike> Oops, I was wrong about that. You can filter on a key and other properties at the same time if you have an index set up to handle it. It would look like this:

```
key = db.Key.from_path('MyModel', 'keyname')
MyModel.all().filter("__key__ =", key).filter('foo = ', 'bar')
```

You can also look up a number of models by their keys, key IDs, or key names with the `get` family of methods.

```
# if you have the key already, or can construct it from its path
models = MyModel.get(Key.from_path(...), ...)

# if you have keys with names
models = MyModel.get_by_key_name('asdf', 'xyz', ...)

# if you have keys with IDs
models = MyModel.get_by_id(123, 456, ...)
```

You can fetch many entities this way. I don't know the exact limit. If any of the keys doesn't exist, you'll get a `None` in the list for that entity.

If you need to filter on some property as well as the key, you'll have to do that in two steps. Either fetch by the keys and check for the property, or query on the property and validate the keys.

Here's an example of filtering after fetching. Note that you don't use the Query class's `filter` method. Instead just filter the list.

```
models = MyModels.get_by_key_name('asdf', ...)

filtered = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.foo == 'bar', models)
```

Comment: Actually I tried that as well.. but after retrieving by list of keys I couldn't `filter`. When I do this: `models = MyModel.get(keys)` the `models.filter('foo =', 'bar')` return an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'`

Comment: Can you update your answer with an example on how can I filter after retrieving them by keys?

Comment: @Lipis You need to insert `.filter()` before `.fetch()`. See my answer for why filtering on keys is a bad idea, though.

Comment: Thanks @Luke that's also something that I wanted to see how it works.. but in general I think this approach wouldn't work..

Answer (score 1):

You can filter queries by doing a GQL Query like this:

```
result = db.GqlQuery('select * from Model where __key__ IN :1', [db.Key.from_path('Model', 'Key1'), db.Key.from_path('Model', 'Key2')]).fetch(2)
```

or

```
result = Model.get([db.Key.from_path('Model', 'Key1'), db.Key.from_path('ProModelduct', 'Key2')])
```

Comment: I still can't use the `result.filter('foo =', 'bar')` in either of them.. or any other way to make the filters possible..

Comment: I don't want to write the whole query right away.. Its easier in steps.. since the number of filters is not known.. can I add a where statement afterwards in a second step?

Comment: Is it possible to combine a `__key__ IN` query with queries on other attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities?hl=de#multiple

```
list_of_entities = ndb.get_multi(list_of_keys)
```